# There is no core free subgroup of order $p^2$ in a group of order $p^4$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

By the classification of group of order $p^4$ ($p$ odd prime) from Burnside's book it seems to me that there is no core free subgroup of order $p^2$ in a group of order $p^4$. If I am not wrong there must be some argument to prove this. Can someone help me in proving this?

Comment: By "core-free", do you mean having a trivial [center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_(group_theory)? A trivial intersection with the overlying group's center? Something else?

Comment: @CameronBuie: http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Core-free_subgroup

Comment: It looks like $H \cap Z(G)$ being trivial is implied by $H$ being core-free, but I'm not sure if they're equivalent

Comment: @user2566092: Right you are. The other direction need not hold. Useless nonsense deleted.

Comment: This core-free thing is pretty funky, I took basic graduate algebra and never encountered that definition.

Comment: In finite nilpotent groups, a subgroup is corefree if and only if it intersects the center trivially. The core of a subgroup is a normal subgroup, so is trivial iff it intersects the center trivially. However $H \cap Z(G)$ is normal in $G$ so contained in the core of $H$.

Comment: At any rate, that means you want to look at groups with small centers, but large elementary abelian subgroups (so that non-normal complements to the center exist). I give such an example below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a partial answer.

Let $K<H<G, |K|=p^2, |H|=p^3$. **Suppose that $H$ is non-abelian.** Since $K$ is normal in $H$, then $Z(H)<K$ (otherwise $H=Z(H)\times K$, what is impossible). Further, $Z(H)$ is characteristic in $H$, hence it is normal in $G$. So the core of $K$ is not trivial.

Comment: When $H$ is abelian, $K$ can be core-free, so your answer is as complete as possible amongst positive answers.

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: Thank you for help! I could not guess how to solve the "easy" part. :-)

Answer (score 5):

Here is the other half of Boris Novikov's answer:

Let $p$ be an odd prime, and let $H=\langle h_1, h_2, h_3 \rangle$ be an elementary abelian subgroup of order $p^3$. Let $x$ act on $H$ as the matrix $$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$ so that $x$ has order $p$ (here we use $p$ odd) and the semidirect product $G=\langle x \rangle \ltimes H$ has order $p^4$.

Then $\langle h_1, h_2 \rangle$ is a core-free subgroup of order $p^2$ (numbering chosen so that $\langle h_3\rangle$, $\langle h_2, h_3 \rangle$, and $\langle h_1, h_2, h_3\rangle$ are normal subgroups of $G$).

In other words, just choose an indecomposable module of length 3 and a vector space complement to its socle.